# In NumPy, how to extract a range from a 1d array without using np.s_?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numba

Assume an array like so:

```
a = np.arange(10)
```

I'd like to delete the numbers from index 2 to 5.

I can do it like this:

```
a = np.delete(a, np.s_[2:6])
```

Now `a` contains `[0, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. However this function is not supported by Numba, and I need to compile this code using Numba.

I would need to accomplish the same using only "basic" NumPy functions (anything here is OK: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html). Unfortunately the `s_` object is not supported.

How can I accomplish this? Its OK if I need to make more than one call or tmp arrays.

Comment: `b = np.delete(a, np.s_[2:6])` doesn't actually do what you want anyway - `a` is unaffected, and `b` gets the value you expected `a` to have.

Comment: aahhh you're correct. I'll fix the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temporary arrays will be created no matter how you do it. You can use some very simple indexing to get what you want:

```
a = np.arange(10)
a = np.delete(a, slice(2, 6))
```

The documentation for [`s_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html) pretty much tells you how to do this in the notes. A 1D call to `s_` is mostly just shorthand for `slice`.

Using [`delete`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) is probably the right choice here because it will allocate the output more efficiently than manually slicing the beginning and end and concentrating.

Comment: When `obj` is a slice, `np.delete` copies chunks of the source to the result.  Beginning and ending chunks are easy copies.  A slice `step` >1 requires special handling.  Because of its generality, I've found `np.delete` is slower than a custom copy (even it is 'smart').

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against deleting from array in numpy as it can be slow (specially for longer arrays, since it copies). Using masks is another way (not sure if numba supports it, worth a try). If you can try to do your operations on masked array:

```
b = a[2:6]
#[2 3 4 5]


#Try to do operations on masked array
a = np.ma.array(a, mask=False)
a.mask[2:6] = True
#[0 1 -- -- -- -- 6 7 8 9]

#if you insist on deleting masked elements
a = a.compressed()
#[0 1 6 7 8 9]
```

Comment: This copies too. In fact, it does more copies.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica If you can do operation without `compressed` wouldn't be faster?

Answer (score 1):

One way using `numpy.arange`:

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def nb_delete(arr, i, j):
    return np.delete(arr, np.arange(i, j))

nb_delete(np.arange(10), 2,6)
```

Output:

```
array([0, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```